# Using cd in RedHat Linux script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script that does some sed changes to HTML files. However, the cd commands don't seem to work... Even though I've used UNIX/Linux for ages, I'm sure this is a newbie question. See my code below.

However, if I take the for loop out and just make it stand on it's own (including the chmod command) and put the cd commands in a separate script with a line that calls the loop script like:

```
cd dir
/home/me/dothisscript
cd ../nextdir
/home/me/dothisscript
cd ../nextdir
/home/me/dothisscript
etc... etc...
```

It works...

This one below does not.

```
cd 1950
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%TITLE%title%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's% - Removethis.com</title>%</title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%<title>Removethis.com %<title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%</title>% - Addthis.com</title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
exec chmod +x *.html
cd ..
cd 1960
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%TITLE%title%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's% - Removethis.com</title>%</title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%<title>Removethis.com %<title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
for i in *.html
do
   sed 's%</title>% - Addthis.com</title>%g' $i > t
   mv t $i
done
exec chmod +x *.html
cd ..
cd 1967
etc... etc...
```

Comment: "*Does not work*" is not a problem description. What does it actually do?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. This has nothing to do with `cd` or loops. You need to look up what `exec` does.

Comment: Nothing after `exec` will be executed. Why are you using `exec chmod` instead of just `chmod`?

Comment: BTW, do you know about the `-i` option to `sed`? It will replace the original file with the result, so you don't need to write to a temporary and then rename it.

Comment: Why are you setting the execute bit on HTML files anyway?

Comment: You can reproduce the problem in two lines -- `exec chmod +x *.html`, and then `echo "why doesn't this execute?"`. Per the [mcve] guidelines in the Help Center, code in questions should be *the shortest possible thing that reproduces the same problem*; if you haven't isolated the shortest reproducer yet, you aren't ready to ask a question.

Comment: For your convenience, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects common problems including this one.

Comment: xbit hack for my Apache. On this server, I am running a very old system - RedHat 5.3. Am working on moving to RedHat 7 now.

Comment: Thank you all for your patience and help. It is VERY MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
exec chmod +x *.html
```

to just

```
chmod +x *.html
```

`exec` replaces the shell process with the specified program, so the rest of the script never executes.